# App script tutorial confusion

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The tutorial is here:  [Tutorial: Writing Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/articles/writing_spreadsheet_data.html)

The full code can be found at the end of the tutorial.

I don't get the for loop in the first function, runExample()

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    if (!dataByDepartment[rowData.department]) {
      dataByDepartment[rowData.department] = [];
      departments.push(rowData.department);
    }
    dataByDepartment[rowData.department].push(rowData);
  }
```

I don't get what is going on inside the **if**-statement.
What do they mean by **dataByDepartment[rowData.department])** ???

**dataByDepartment** is initially empty... Is this creating a property??

Can someone please explain what that whole loop is doing?  Thank you very much!

PS: I am still quite new to Javascript... Coming from C programming I am always confused by the object and property creations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general terms the function of the loop is to populate the `dataByDepartment` object with one property for each (distinct) department, where each property will reference an array of data applicable to that department. Each iteration of the loop first checks whether there is already a property for the current department and if not it creates it. If it does need to create a new property it also adds the department to the `departments` array.

Some background: the following statement creates an object with initially no properties:

```
var dataByDepartment = {};
```

To assign a property "key1" with the value "value1" to that object you would then say:

```
dataByDepartment.key1 = "value1";
// or
dataByDepartment["key1"] = "value1";
```

Note that if a property called "key1" already existed it would be overwritten. The square-bracket syntax allows you to use property key names that are variable. So you can say:

```
var myKey = "key2";
dataByDepartment[myKey] = "value2";
```

Which will create a property with a name equal to whatever `myKey` evaluates to ("key2" in this case), and the value "value2".

So getting back to the actual code you quote, the if statement:

```
if (!dataByDepartment[rowData.department]) {
```

is checking whether `dataByDepartment` already has a property with a key name equal to whatever is in `rowData.department`. The syntax is a shortcut roughly equivalent to `if (dataByDepartment[rowData.department] != undefined)`.

The first statement in the `if`:

```
dataByDepartment[rowData.department] = [];
```

creates a new property with the key name of whatever is in `rowData.department` and the value of a new empty array. At that point if the property already existed it would be overwritten by a new empty array, hence the if test.

The second statement in the `if` adds the department name to the `departments` array:

```
departments.push(rowData.department);
```

Finally, after the `if`, the array referenced by `dataByDepartment[rowData.department]` has a new element added to it:

```
dataByDepartment[rowData.department].push(rowData);
```

Comment: Great explanation. Really walked me through step by step. Completely understood.  Thanks, bro!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting there.

```
dataByDepartment[rowData.department]

// is the same as
var myKey = rowData.department // you can use dot or bracket notation
dataByDepartment[myKey]
```

If the key exists then it is not **undefined** - it will evaluate **true**. If the key does not exist then it is **undefined** - it will evaluate **false**

So the if statement is the same as this

```
if ( !dataByDepartment[myKey]) {

// which is logically the same as (note that === does not coerce type)
if ( typeof(dataByDepartment[myKey]) === 'undefined' ) {
```

Ask if you need more clarification :)

Comment: If the key does not exist then it is `undefined`, not `null`, though of course that still evaluates as falsy. `undefined == null` is true, but `undefined === null` is false.

Comment: Thanks for the nice and short introductory and explanation. Concise. Good job :) Thanks a lot martin.

Comment: @nnnnnn You are correct. Sorry I wasn't paying attention (will edit)